# Authorize.net Refund always returning "The sum of credits against the referenced transaction would exceed original debit amount"

Tags: php, authorize.net

Iam working on a Refunding a transaction with Authorize.net, but it always returning -"The sum of credits against the referenced transaction would exceed original debit amount".

I have submitted following fields that are needed for a refund along with other necessary fields

1) previously settled transaction id as "x_trans_id"
2) Correct transaction amount as "x_amount"
3) transaction type "x_type" => "credit"
4) x_method = "cc"

Here I'm quite sure that Iam submitting correct amount for refund request, but still getting the above error. Also this previously settled transaction was used x_type" as "auth_capture".

Please note, Iam working on LIVE server with all details are correct(Authorize.net merchant username and password, customer card details etc).

Please can anyone tell me why Iam getting such an error while sending a request for refund ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the control panel to verify the amount of the original transaction to make sure it is what you are expecting? Also, what was the date of the original transaction?

Comment: Transaction was done on 2011/07/13. I do not have merchant login access to check the control panel. Is there any service charge or deduction for refund ?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you are requesting a refund for an amount greater than the initial payment amount of the initial transaction. So if you are trying to refund an amount greater then the amount charged on 2011/07/13 then you will get this error.